# Skrollr init set <body> height to be too high

Tags: javascript, parallax, skrollr

I used Skrollr library to create parallax effect for the background. However, when skillor.init() is called, the body height is too high and create extra space below in the page.

The problem can be seen here:
http://codepen.io/designil/pen/Ggxde

HTML:

```
<div class="headrow">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <h1 class="logo"><a href="#">21GUNS</a></h1>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-9">
      <div class="topmenu">
        <p>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a>
        </p>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li>
           <div class="dropdown">
  <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">MENU 1</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">MENU 2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">MENU 3</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">MENU 4</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">MENU 5</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div><!-- headrow -->

<div class="bannerrow">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/1800x600" alt="" />
</div>

<div class="servicerow" data-top-bottom="background-position: 50% 75%;" data-bottom-top="background-position: 50% 100%;">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
        <header>
          <h2>21SERVICES</h2>
          <p>Drive next-generation technologies vortals engage, systems services dynamic to our clients.</p>
        </header>
      </div>
    </div><!-- row -->

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="column2-box">
          <i class="fa fa-gift fa-fw"></i>
          <h3>FLAT DESIGN</h3>
          <p>End-to-end, user-centred web-readiness cultivate granular drive convergence.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="column2-box">
          <i class="fa fa-gift fa-fw"></i>
          <h3>FLAT DESIGN</h3>
          <p>End-to-end, user-centred web-readiness cultivate granular drive convergence.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- row -->

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="column2-box">
          <i class="fa fa-gift fa-fw"></i>
          <h3>FLAT DESIGN</h3>
          <p>End-to-end, user-centred web-readiness cultivate granular drive convergence.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="column2-box">
          <i class="fa fa-gift fa-fw"></i>
          <h3>FLAT DESIGN</h3>
          <p>End-to-end, user-centred web-readiness cultivate granular drive convergence.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- row -->


  </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skrollr/0.6.11/skrollr.min.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```
@blue: #293448;
@red: #C1392B;

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.headrow {
  background: @blue;
}

.logo a {
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.3s;

  &:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #eee;
  }
}

.topmenu {
  text-align: right;

  p {
    margin-top: 10px;

    a {
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0 5px;
      text-align: right;
    }
  }

  ul {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }

  li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 30px;

    a {
      color: #eee;
      display: block;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
      border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }

    a:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
      border-bottom: 3px solid @red;
    }

    .dropdown-menu {
      text-align: left;

      li {
        margin: 0;
        display: block;
      }

      a:hover {
        background: #ccc;
      }

      a {
        color: @blue;
        border: 0;
        transition: 0;
      }
    }
  }
}

.bannerrow {
  img { width: 100%; height: auto;}
}

.servicerow {
  color: #fff;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/pIaoyxQ.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;

  header {
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;

    h2 { margin-bottom: 10px; }

    p { font-size: 13pt; }
  }
}
  .column2-box {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 15px 0;

    i { font-size: 110px; float: left; }

    h3 { margin-top: 0; }

  }
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
  $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();

   $('.dropdown').hover(function() {
      $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(200);
    }, function() {
      $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(200);
    });

  var s = skrollr.init({forceHeight: false});
});
```

I am not sure which element makes the page too high.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

```
skrollr.init({forceHeight: false});
```

https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr#forceheighttrue

Skrollr makes sure you can actually reach `data-bottom-top`. As you can see, the gap allows the element's bottom to be perfectly aligned with the top of the viewport.

Comment: Thank you Prinzhorn for saving my life once again! I have tried adding {forceHeight: true} but never fix this :/ (Obviously)

Comment: It seems that in order to use the skrollr 'pausing' feature, `forceHeight` needs to be set to true, is that correct? Is there a workaround for that? Either for the pausing to work with `forceHeight: false`, or another method for fixing the extra space at the bottom of the page?

Comment: There's no such thing as a pausing feature in skrollr

Comment: I was having the same issue and this really helped. Thank you. This is a great library and I hope you (Prinzhorn) decide to keep it alive. Thank you again.